# Why when instantiating prefab to duplicate it it's duplicating double of the amount and some in wrong position and rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script that save the transforms information and then load back and instantiate a prefab at the same positions and rotations of the saved transforms information.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEditor;

public static class TransformSaver
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Transform
    {
        public string sceneName;
        public string name;
        public UnityEngine.Transform parent;
        public Vector3 pos;
        public Quaternion rot;
        public Vector3 scale;
    }

    //Save Transform
    public static void SaveTransform(UnityEngine.GameObject[] tranformToSave)
    {
        Transform[] trnfrm = new Transform[tranformToSave.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < trnfrm.Length; i++)
        {
            trnfrm[i] = new Transform();

            trnfrm[i].sceneName = tranformToSave[i].gameObject.scene.name;
            trnfrm[i].name = tranformToSave[i].name;
            trnfrm[i].parent = tranformToSave[i].transform.parent;
            trnfrm[i].pos = tranformToSave[i].transform.position;
            trnfrm[i].rot = tranformToSave[i].transform.rotation;
            trnfrm[i].scale = tranformToSave[i].transform.localScale;
        }

        string jsonTransform = JsonHelper.ToJson(trnfrm, true);
        File.WriteAllText(@"e:\json\json.txt", jsonTransform);
    }

    public static Transform[] LoadTransforms()
    {
        string jsonTransform = File.ReadAllText(@"e:\json\json.txt");
        if (jsonTransform == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Transform[] savedTransforms = JsonHelper.FromJson<Transform>(jsonTransform);

        return savedTransforms;
    }

    //Load Transform
    public static Transform[] LoadTransform(bool usePrefab, GameObject prefab, bool useSceneName, string sceneName)
    {
        string jsonTransform = File.ReadAllText(@"e:\json\json.txt");
        if (jsonTransform == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Transform[] savedTransforms = JsonHelper.FromJson<Transform>(jsonTransform);

        for (int i = 0; i < savedTransforms.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (useSceneName)
                {
                    SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName(sceneName));
                }
                else
                {
                    SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName(savedTransforms[i].sceneName));
                }
            }

            if (usePrefab == true && prefab != null)
            {
                GameObject go = UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate(prefab);

                go.transform.position = savedTransforms[i].pos;
                go.transform.rotation = savedTransforms[i].rot;
                go.transform.transform.SetParent(savedTransforms[i].parent);

            }
        }
        return savedTransforms;
    }
}
```

Then the editorwindow script for buttons and prefab select to duplicate :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class SaveTransformsInfo : EditorWindow
{
    public GameObject source;

    [MenuItem("Tools/Save Transforms")]
    private static void CreateReplaceWithPrefab()
    {
        const int width = 340;
        const int height = 70;

        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        GetWindow<SaveTransformsInfo>().position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Select Prefab", GUILayout.Width(80));
        source = (GameObject)EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(source, typeof(GameObject), true, GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        GUILayout.Space(35);

        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Transforms"))
        {
            TransformSaver.SaveTransform(Selection.gameObjects);
        }

        GUILayout.Space(2);

        if (GUILayout.Button("Load Transforms"))
        {
            TransformSaver.LoadTransform(true, source, false, "");
        }
    }
}
```

And the json file part of the content example :

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "sceneName": "Example_01",
            "name": "Wall_Door_Long_01",
            "parent": {
                "instanceID": -692606
            },
            "pos": {
                "x": 24.0,
                "y": 55.0,
                "z": -25.0
            },
            "rot": {
                "x": -0.7071068286895752,
                "y": 0.0,
                "z": 0.0,
                "w": 0.7071068286895752
            },
            "scale": {
                "x": 1.0,
                "y": 1.0,
                "z": 1.0
            }
        },
        {
            "sceneName": "Example_01",
            "name": "Wall_Door_Long_01",
            "parent": {
                "instanceID": 393488
            },
            "pos": {
                "x": 16.0,
                "y": 50.0,
                "z": -26.99999237060547
            },
            "rot": {
                "x": 0.0,
                "y": 0.7071065902709961,
                "z": 0.0,
                "w": -0.7071069478988648
            },
            "scale": {
                "x": 1.0,
                "y": 1.0,
                "z": 1.0
            }
        },
```

But in the end I'm getting 18 new duplicated prefabs and more 18 clones duplicated prefabs that's 36 instead of 18. And some of them at the same position and rotation as the saved transforms but some of them are standing under the others with some other position and rotation :

[image: Duplicated Prefabs]

In the screenshot the door marked with red circle is the fine duplicated prefab.
The one marked with green circle is the prefab that is under the red one and should not be created at all with wrong position and rotation.

On the right in the list all the objects in black are the new duplicated prefabs including the clones. The objects in blue are the saved transforms.

The main goal is duplicate a prefab at the same saved transforms positions and rotations including parent if they have.

Comment: You're going to need to debug your own code. There isn't enough here for us to figure out what's wrong. It could be anything from an extra object in your json file (you only included 2, when its clear 3 are spawned), which could have resulted from an error in the saving, or it could be a problem with the loading (e.g. you save parents using the instance ID: what happens when a saved object is the child of another saved object?).

Comment: I tried also without the json file without my code att this simple code in the video tutorial and it did same mess. So I guess it's something with my objects can't figure out yet I will have to dig. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FhVMFMG97Q

Comment: Ok I found the problem not yet how to solve it but found what make it. I have 18 objects selected in the hierarchy with the same name.  All of them have the name : Wall_Door_Long_01. The problem is when I filter by name in the search bar in the hierarchy I'm getting also each door child that have the same name as parent. Each door parent name and one of the childs are Wall_door_Long_01 and when replacing instead replacing only the parent it also replacing the child. Now I wonder how can I identify if the Wall_Long_01 is parent or child and replace only parents ?

Comment: And the parent Wall_Door_Long_01 is it self a child ofanother parent so how can I check make sure that when replacing the Wall_Door_Long_01 it will be the Wall_Door_Long_01 parent and it's child ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to refactor something.